# Localization issue in Laravel 10 - missing parameter error

Tags: laravel, routes, parameters, hyperlink, localization

How can I fix the "Missing required parameter for [Route: TEST] [URI: {language}/test/{w}] [Missing parameter: w]" error in Laravel 10 when using localization? I have a route, controller method, and link that all seem to be correct, and when I click the link, the URL appears to be correct, but I am still receiving the error. I have already tried using the "route" helper function with the correct parameters, but the error persists.

I have a Laravel 10 project and I'm facing a localization issue. I have a route defined like this:

```
Route::get('{language}/test/{w}', [testController::class, 'Ctest'])->name('TEST');
```

In the controller, I have a method defined like this:

```
public function Ctest($language, $w)
{
    return view('welcome', [
        "w" => $w,
        "lan" => $language,
    ]);
}
```

I also have a link defined like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('TEST', ['en', 1161]) }}">TEST</a>
```

However, when I click on the link, I get the following error:

Missing required parameter for [Route: TEST] [URI: {language}/test/{w}] [Missing parameter: w].

But the link seems to be working correctly and I can see "/en/test/1161" in the URL. Additionally, when I use dd($language, $w) in the controller, I get the correct values of "en" and "1161".

Can someone please help me figure out why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: If you are able to do a `dd` in the controller then the problem is not there, surely in the `welcome` view you are creating another link and that is where you need to pass the parameter.

Comment: I am deeply grateful for your helpful comment which led me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<a href="{{ route('TEST', ['language' => 'en', 'w' => 1161]) }}">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have actually tried that already but it doesn't seem to work. When I changed my link to the suggested format, like this: {{ route('TEST', ['language' => 'en', 'w' => 1161])}}, I still get the same error: 'Missing required parameter for [Route: TEST] [URI: {language}/test/{w}] [Missing parameter: w]'. Is there anything else I can try?"

Comment: what happened after clicking the link, in browser url input?

Comment: browsers address bar shows the link correctly "/en/test/1161", but the error persist , "Missing required parameter for [Route: TEST] [URI: {language}/test/{w}] [Missing parameter: w]."

Comment: make sure to use this url in your view for one time or you can pass correct parameter to all of another "TEST" route

Comment: i do not know what wrong with the view , this is the only content that i wrote in the view : 
<div style="margin-top: 200px; ">
        php dd($w, $lan, app()->getLocale())  endphp
    <h1>
        {{$w}}_ {{$lan}}
    </h1>
</div>
the dd() working correct and pass all parameters like this 
"1161" // resources\views/welcome.blade.php
"en" // resources\views/welcome.blade.php
"en" // resources\views/welcome.blade.php
, but when i delete the dd() , the error shows up again.

Comment: now I found out something is wrong with my layout view, which is included in the page.
thanks for your suggestions it was a productive conversation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the language switcher in the layout where i wrote :

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['language' => 'en'])}}">English</a></li>
```

Route::currentRouteName() function returns the name of the current route, which in this case is "TEST", but it does not include any parameters that were passed to that route.